# CONVERT_TZ in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, dst, convert-tz

How exactly do I use this with the following code to counteract DST with +1hr:

```
SELECT datetime 
FROM events 
WHERE datetime > NOW() 
GROUP BY datetime 
ORDER BY datetime
```

I can't quite work out how I do this from the various examples I've seen on the internet such as:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(datetime,'+00:00','+01:00')
```

Cheers!

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result on http://sqlfiddle.com as it's not absolutely clear to me, what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(datetime,'+00:00','+01:00') as conv_dt
FROM events
WHERE datetime > NOW() 
GROUP BY conv_dt 
ORDER BY conv_dt;
```

Comment: The page won't even load now with the above code as the statement in my model file...

Comment: Well, from a SQL point of view this is correct, please show me your full code, maybe i can help you then.